# Equicontinuity of continuous families of maps between topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be locally convex, Hausdorff topological vector spaces and let $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$.  Let $f: [a,b] \to \hom(X,Y)$ be continuous, where $\hom(X,Y)$ is the space of continuous linear maps from $X$ to $Y$ with the topology of uniform convergence on bounded subsets of $X$.  Let $H \subset \hom(X,Y)$ be the image of $f$.

1. Is $H$ always an equicontinuous subset of $\hom(X,Y)?$  This is true in the case where $X$ is barelled by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, but I do not want to make any additional assumptions on $X$ or $Y$.
2. If $H$ need not be equicontinuous in general, can we make any modifications to $f$ to ensure it is?  e.g. assuming $f$ is infinitely differentiable, or continuous with respect to a different topology on $\hom(X,Y)$.  Again, I do not want to make any additional assumptions about the spaces $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: What is meant by a bounded subset of $X$?

Comment: A subset $B \subset X$ is bounded if $\sup_{x \in B} p(x) < \infty$ for every seminorm $p$ in the family that generates the locally convex topology on $X$.

Comment: I have not checked, what follows might be completely wrong.
H is compact in a space of continuous functions, subspace
of the continuous functions on X (with the weak topology)
with the compact-open topology. Use Ascoli - Arzela.

Comment: @NN - Thanks for the comment.  Which version of Arzela-Ascoli are you referring to?  Usually there is a strong restriction on the type of space $X$ is, e.g. $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space.  Did you consider the weak topology on $X$ so that it would satisfy some weaker hypothesis?

Comment: Ascoli theorem in Engelking, general topology, where domain is a
k-space. Note that X and Y can be supposed to be complete (linear
functions extend to the completion). However, I forgot that the
k-modification of the weak topology is something well known to be 
useful only for Banach spaces (Eberlein-Smullyan). In any case,
the obtained equicontinuity is for a different topology on X (I 
realize now that you can change the topology on the space of 
functions, not in X). Sorry
(also for the delay; I had lost the question until a posted answer
re-put today the question in the first page).


Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there is a sequence $T_n\in hom(X,Y)$ which converges to $0$ uniformly on all
bounded subsets of $X$ but is not equicontinuous (such a sequence should exist if $X$ fails to be $c_0$-*quasibarrelled*, see chapter 8.2 of the book *Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces* of J. Bonet and P. Perez Carreras). I believe that the function $f:[0,1] \to hom(X,Y)$
defined by $f(0)=0$, $f(1/n)=T_n$ and affine-linear interpolation (e.g. $f(t/n + (1-t)/(n+1))
= tT_n + (1-t) T_{n+1}$ for $t\in [0,1]$ and $n\in \mathbb N$) should be continuous
but the range is not equicontinuous. It should also be possible to make a smooth variant out of this example.

Comment: Thanks.  I think what I was really after (though I didn't ask it) was if a compact subset of $\hom(X,Y)$ is automatically equicontinuous.  Your convergent sequence alone answers that question.